# Why won't JButton.setBounds work in a for loop?

Tags: java, swing, animation, jbutton, mouselistener

The setBounds methods works fine if it's not in a for loop but the moment I place it in a for lopp it seizes to work why is this?

```
btnResize.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            //This re sizes the JButton.
            btnResize.setBounds(10, 11 ,100, 100);

            //This does nothing
            for(int i = 0; i < 500; i ++) {
                btnResize.setBounds(i, i , i, i);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: 1: It happens really really fast. 2: The window/frame isn't graphically updated instantly.

Comment: Why are even trying to do so ? If you are using layout manager: you should not be using `setBounds` at all. And if you say that you are interested to make a moving animation, then doing that in this way is not appropriate either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing this in the UI thread, which means nothing in the UI has a chance to react to it until the loop has finished... only the last `setBounds` call will really have any visible effect.

If you're trying to perform animation, you'll need to use a timer of some description so that you can repeatedly make a small change, wait (without blocking the UI thread) and then make another change etc. (You probably don't want to use `setBounds` for that anyway, but that's a slightly different matter.)
Note that you still need to make the changes on the UI thread, as they're UI changes - you just need to let the UI *react* to the change before you make the next one.

See the [tutorial on Swing timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: @mKorbel: Edited - see if you think that's better.

Comment: Answer is close to appropriate for setting location and size for components. However while GUI rendering, the true reason is that, Even if we make several change to Swing GUI paintings, Swing is smart enough to wrap all those change to one single painting request with calculation of every single pixel that needs to be updated for the final GUI rendering inside  EDT by `repaint()` call on the component. And, in fact while Animating components moving, It is always preferable to use a buffer strategy: Using an image containing the paint of the target component and move the image.

Comment: @Sage: regardless of wrapping all the changes in one go, if the UI thread is buys making further changes, it's still not going to be able to respond is it? The core of this answer - that making multiple changes in one go doesn't work as the OP desired - is true for both kinds of change, isn't it?

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes, that is why the answer is necessarily close to correct. But not exactly correct ;) The fact is that the, EDT can be busy performing other task but  it will eventually execute the painting task submitted to it by Swing GUI rendering mechanism into Event Queue(As it is more likely obvious that for custom painting `invokeLater` and `reapint` come into play always).

Comment: For instance, if OP  now tries to move the component using Swing Timer but put several subsequent `repaint()` call with changes of Bounds inside same action event , The effect which he might expect to see won't be intercepted but only the final updated GUI with *all those changes and repaint call* done inside that single action event. It is more like about Swing's rendering mechanism rather than the fact that EDT is busy That is why i said: For moving the answer is OK, but animation is more about doing things with custom painting. :) I hope you will understand me.

Comment: @Sage: I suggest you add your own answer... It's more appropriate to go into that sort of detail in an answer than in comments, and I'm not in a good position to edit it into my answer right now.

Comment: @JonSkeet, sorry quickly typed. I will make an answer as you asked. But please allow me a little while as i am a little busy. StackOverflow constantly keeps attract me as a magnet and take all of my time, hence my food too ;) That is why recently i make comments rather than answering question. But please i will be back, make and answer and will notify you :)